# Gmail Contextual Gadget OAuth 1.0 to 2.0 migration

Tags: gmail, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace, gmail-contextual-gadgets

We have a Gmail Contextual Gadget, it is published in Google Apps Marketplace.
For OAuth1.0 to 2.0 migration, as recommended in https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v1migratev2 we created a new version of our Gmail Contextual Gadget, published it in Google Apps Marketplace, and associated it with the old version.

Now, to the question: the old version of the gadget was installed in about 50 domains. What happens to them after September, 30? Do they migrate automatically? Or what do we need to do so that our users could continue using our gadget?

UPD:

As soitof pointed out, Step 4 of the migration guide suggests that we call 'PUT https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/upgradableApp/listingID/cwsID/domain'

Yet, I am unsure about how to proceed from here. Namely, what the migration strategy should be.

The first thing is that we don't keep the list of domains where our gadget is installed, 
we only have the number of domains. I suppose we could track the requests and build that list.

Here comes the second point: do we fire that PUT requests manually? It is not difficult for our 50 domains, but what if there were, say, 10000? My wild guess would be that we make the old version of our app fire that PUT request automatically, but I am not sure if that's a good idea.

I would welcome some advice, 'best practices', 'guidelines' etc. on how it is usually done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they will not migrate automatically, you have to migrate them. Its a simple task you just need a bit of info about your old and new app.

All the info is found here: 
https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v1migratev2

UPDATE: 
So to migrate you will need two versions of your gadget published, one in the old market place and one in the new one.

So right now you have your old GamV1 gadget listed, you'll need to submit your new one for publishing. Once it is approved, and listed, you can begin the migration. You have to wait till it's published since you need information from its public listing.

You'll need to build a list of domains and perform the PUT on each one manually. I made a script that performed the PUT on a domain name, then made a wrapper script that fed it domains one by one.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not yet clear. I added more detail in the original question.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps. @AlexeyVashchenko